# Get idle consumer container listener details in kafka spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have setup my dynamic consumer as follows so that i can pass my topic name and create listener for it:

```
@Component
public class MessageListenerConfigurer {

 @Autowired
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String,String> createContainerForTopic(String topicName) {

 ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer(topicName);

 container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new InstantMessageListener());
}
}
```

```
package org.kafka.listener;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.kafka.service.MessageDbService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InstantMessageListener implements MessageListener<String, String> {
    public InstantMessageListener(){
    }

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Transactional
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record) {
        log.info("My message listener got a new record: " + record);
        log.info("message is: "+record.toString());
        log.warn("onMessage:: ===== from eventhub topic: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}, message: {}, timestamp: {}",
                record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset(), record.value(), record.timestamp());
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::sleep).join();
        log.info("My message listener done processing record: " + record);


    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void sleep() {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

I am trying to see if there are any idle containers so that instead of generating new container for same topic everytime, I can reuse it  and efficiently implement the thread mechanism but **below code is giving empty response**.

```
package org.kafka.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.SingletonBeanRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
class ExportController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @GetMapping("/beans")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    String[] registeredBeans() {
        return printBeans();
    }

    private String[] printBeans() {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        if (autowireCapableBeanFactory instanceof ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) {
            String[] singletonNames = ((SingletonBeanRegistry) autowireCapableBeanFactory).getSingletonNames();
            for (String singleton : singletonNames) {
                System.out.println(singleton);
            }
            return singletonNames;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Kindlt help.

Comment: Perhaps you can listen on Spring application event [ListenerContainerIdleEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#events) instead.

Comment: @ChinHuang problem is if another consumer is started from rest api even even before this consumer stops as specified in the time for  idle event.It leads to duplication